# What's up with all these Death Note Questions lately?

Tags: discussion

I don't really know if this questions fits here or should go to chat but I'm really curious about this, I ask this in the Meta.

What is going on with all these Death Note questions? 
People come up with all different of fictional events and ask if this or that scenario would work with the Death Note rules. It slightly starts to annoy me to be honest. I mean a suspicious mind could even wonder if people try to farm reputation with these, since there are a lot of rule and they are pretty strict and absolute and people try to somehow squeeze between the rules.

Death Note is a great Anime! But it's also quite old by now so, is there a new Death Note hype I missed or where does this trend comes from?

Comment: I'm not sure what more we can do than to speculate why. You can ask the question askers?...

Comment: Well, i makre this as a discussion since i'd liek to hear other opinions about it :D

Comment: As for the reason why so many showed up recently. It's probably partly my fault. My *next tag badge* was [tag:Death-Note], so I went to look for unanswered *death-note* questions and seeing as there were quite a few, I started answering them. They aren't new, but as to whether they are all on-topic is another matter though. I'm quite sure this will even out again in a few days. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not sure why people ask them though as I personally only asked 3 of them, but if I'm honest then answering would have been for reputation farming as I have basically been trying to get the *mortarboard* and *death-note tag* badge the last two days. Again sorry about that, I'll not do so in the future.

Comment: Btw related posts are [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1099/6166) and [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2282/6166)

Comment: @PeterRaeves: I think there is nothing to be sorry about or refrain from doing here. The questions are on topic (as far as the cited meta discussions go), so it's not wrong to provide an answer to them. It's better than leaving them with unanswered.

Comment: @PeterRaeves that explains a lot :D TBH i didn't checked the date of these questions and ofc its better to answer them then leave them open, so pls don't stop to share your wisdom with us :D It was just really spooky to see this army of deathnote questions :D

Comment: Honestly, the "identification request" questions are more irritating than the Death Note questions, (Disclaimer: I posted one of those recent Death Note questions.) but I see your point and you could do what I did with the "identification request" questions: add it to the ignored tags, then hide ignored tags in your profile.

Comment: Also, since this topic was raised, I want to point out that I am most certainly not farming reputation. I had been on a 17 month "hiatus" recently, and another 4 month "hiatus" not long before that one. My reputation is already **OVER 9000!!** and it could have been 20k+ easily. PS: By the way, please visit my profile and upvote some of my answers. ;-) Not too many at a time, it would get reversed for serial upvoting. :-P

Comment: I think it's a trend, people saw how interesting the questions were, and then came up with concepts that "couldn't be beat" or to find a plot hole, I for one asked one in hopes of doing this.

Comment: i'm not actually saying that peaple do it for farming rep, just that there is a possibility that people could read it that way :D perdefault i believe that everyone here acts nice :)

Comment: ofc finding plot holes is funny but as in other meta post mentioned these questions always have a bit of speculation and opinion in them even in the  pretty accurate ruled world of death note

Comment: To be honest, I also get annoyed with all these academic "Can the Death Note kill somebody whose face was eaten off by rabid cuttlefish?" type questions too, but they are and should be on-topic. SciFi and Fantasy SE often fields questions that ask answerers to speculate within the established rules of a fictional universe.

Comment: By the way, its a good thing you don't use your real name and real picture here. ;-)